# Google App Script - Import ALL range formatting between 2 SpreadSheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Update: I wrote for loops to fix the merged cell and column width issues. Just need some help with the borders!

I'm working on copying a range of cells from one Google Spreadsheet to another Google Spreadsheet. The difficult part is that I'm trying to keep ALL formatting. I have been able to preserve all of the formatting thus far, except for 3 items: cell borders, various merged cells, and column width. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Sorry in advance, just found out about Google App Script yesterday and I've never used JS before.

```
function importTable() {

  // Source spreadsheet
  var srcSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadSheet-ID");
  var scrSheet = srcSpreadSheet.setActiveSheet(srcSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1"));

  // Destination spreadsheet
  var destSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadSheet-ID");
  var destSheet = destSpreadSheet.setActiveSheet(destSpreadSheet.getSheetByName("Test"));
  destSheet.clear();

  // Get data and formatting from the source sheet
  var range = scrSheet.getRange(1, 2, 24, 16);

  var values = range.getValues();
  var background = range.getBackgrounds();
  var banding = range.getBandings();
  var mergedRanges = range.getMergedRanges();
  var fontColor = range.getFontColors();
  var fontFamily = range.getFontFamilies();
  var fontLine = range.getFontLines();
  var fontSize = range.getFontSizes();
  var fontStyle = range.getFontStyles();
  var fontWeight = range.getFontWeights();
  var horAlign = range.getHorizontalAlignments();
  var textStyle = range.getTextStyles();
  var vertAlign = range.getVerticalAlignments();

  // Put data and formatting in the destination sheet
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 2, 24, 16);

  destRange.setValues(values);
  destRange.setBackgrounds(background);
  destRange.setFontColors(fontColor);
  destRange.setFontFamilies(fontFamily);
  destRange.setFontLines(fontLine);
  destRange.setFontSizes(fontSize);
  destRange.setFontStyles(fontStyle);
  destRange.setFontWeights(fontWeight);
  destRange.setHorizontalAlignments(horAlign);
  destRange.setTextStyles(textStyle);
  destRange.setVerticalAlignments(vertAlign);

    // Iterate through to put merged ranges in place
  for (var i = 0; i < mergedRanges.length; i++) {
    destSheet.getRange(mergedRanges[i].getA1Notation()).merge();
  }

  // Iterate through to get the column width of the source destination
  for (var i = 1; i < 18; i++) {
    var width = scrSheet.getColumnWidth(i);
    destSheet.setColumnWidth(i, width);
  }

  // Iterate through to get the row heighth of the source destination
  for (var i = 1; i < 27; i++){
    var height = scrSheet.getRowHeight(i);
    destSheet.setRowHeight(i, height);
  }

}
```

Comment: You need to check out the [Range Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) to find the properties you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I've checked out all the methods in the range class and I can't find a get for borders and that is my biggest issue.

Comment: You are correct.  There is a [set](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbordertop-left-bottom-right-vertical-horizontal), but no get.  I never noticed that.  I'm afraid I'm no help any longer.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this workaround? In this workaround, copyTo() of Class Sheet and copyTo() of Class Range are used. I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

The flow of this script is as follows.

1. Copy a sheet including the range you want to copy as a template using copyTo() of Class Sheet.
2. Copy values, formulas, formats and merges from the copied sheet to the destination sheet using copyTo() of Class Range.

   - At that time, the range you want to copy is used.
3. Copy column width from from the copied sheet to the destination sheet using copyTo() of Class Range.
4. Delete the template sheet.

#### Sample script :

```
function importTable2() {
  // Source
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadSheet-ID").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1, 2, 24, 16);

  // Destination
  var destSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SpreadSheet-ID");
  var destSheet = destSS.getSheetByName("Test");
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 2, 24, 16);
  destSheet.clear();

  // Copy
  var copiedsheet = sourceRange.getSheet().copyTo(destSS);
  copiedsheet.getRange(sourceRange.getA1Notation()).copyTo(destRange);
  copiedsheet.getRange(sourceRange.getA1Notation()).copyTo(destRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_COLUMN_WIDTHS, false);
  destSS.deleteSheet(copiedsheet);
}
```

#### Note :

- Before you run this script, please set `SpreadSheet-ID`.

#### References :

- [copyTo() of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet)
- [copyTo() of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: @cmbramwell I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.