# Copying part of a row from one Google spreadsheet to another google spreadsheet based on a value in a cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am trying to write a script to copy column B:K of a specific row based on if column 11 (K) has a "Y" on it.

I have scripts that move from one sheet to another within the same spreadsheet that work just fine but I am really struggling with one spreadsheet to another and only moving part of the row instead of the whole thing.

Below is the script thus far... would love help!

```
function onEdit() {
    var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("15RWoaW8tRLVGOTDrZvBLJwx0beWEsV3x8pfwGe2zMfc").getSheetByName("2018 2 Week Snapshot for Jim"); // sss = source spreadsheet
    var r = sss.getActiveRange();

    if(sss.getName() == "2018 2 Week Snapshot for Jim" && r.getColumn() == 11 && r.getValue() == "Y") {
        var row = r.getRow();
        var numColumns = sss.getLastColumn();
        var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1dSJOOw_oLVc6Nf-C0MY9715tZGuh69kR6-j_m8EJ-So"); // tss = target spreadsheet
        var targetSheet = tss.getSheetByName("Test Sheet"); // ts = target sheet
        var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        tss.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    }

}
```

This is my new code, still struggling:

```
function onEdit() {
    var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('15RWoaW8tRLVGOTDrZvBLJwx0beWEsV3x8pfwGe2zMfc'); // sss = source spreadsheet
    var ss = sss.getSheetByName('2018 2 Week Snapshot for Jim'); // ss = source sheet
    var SRange = ss.getRange("C:K");

    if(ss.getName() == "2018 2 Week Snapshot for Jim" && SRange.getColumn() == 9 && SRange.getValue() == "y") {
        var row = SRange.getRow();
        var numColumns = ss.getLastColumn();
        var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1dSJOOw_oLVc6Nf-C0MY9715tZGuh69kR6-j_m8EJ-So'); // tss = target spreadsheet
        var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Test Sheet'); // ts = target sheet
        var target = ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
        ss.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).SetValues(target);     
    } 
}
```

Comment: When the source and destination spreadsheet are difference, ``copyTo()`` cannot be used. In order to copy to other spreadsheet, there are several workarounds. So can I ask you about your situation? You want to copy only values to other Spreadsheet? Or you want to copy values and formulas to other Spreadsheet? In these cases, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833094/set-values-to-ranges-in-a-different-spreadsheet/51833334#51833334) might be useful.

Comment: Or you want to values, formulas and formats to other Spreadsheet? In these cases, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51885452/google-app-script-import-all-range-formatting-between-2-spreadsheets/51887793#51887793) might be useful.

Comment: @Tanaike Data is being sent from a calendar to the 1st spreadsheet. A group of people will be reviewing the data with multiple people. Then, after they perform a specific action in column K (putting a "Y") the data that is relevant to a different group gets sent to their spreadsheet.

Comment: @Tanaike - To answer your questions; there are no formulas or formats I am trying to keep. I am only looking to copy the values in the cells from Spreadsheet 1 to Spreadsheet 2.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that in the case of copying only values to other spreadsheet, [this information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833094/set-values-to-ranges-in-a-different-spreadsheet/51833334#51833334) is useful for you. This is also about the method for copying values from Spreadsheet A to Spreadsheet B. But if this was not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: @Tanaike - I have updated my code but still am struggling. Are you able to help me any further?

Comment: I'm really sorry for the inconvenience and poor English skill. I posted an answer by including the modification points of your script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, feel free to tell me. I would like to study to solve your issues.

Comment: @Tanaike When I tried your code I got the following error "TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 6, file "Code")"

Comment: I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. You use ``onEdit()`` of simple trigger in your question. This modified script is also used it. But in your script, you use ``SpreadsheetApp.openById()``. So the installable trigger is required to be used in this situation. So please use ``myFunction(e)`` as an installable trigger. From your error message, it seems that you don't install ``myFunction`` as an trigger. Could you please install the function as an trigger and try it again.

Comment: @Tanaike I appreciate your help with this. Unfortunately my parameters were changed and I was told never to change my question so I have posted a new one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52179951/script-for-copying-parts-of-a-google-spreadsheet-row-to-another-spreadsheet-and

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about your situation. If my answer was not what you want, I would like to apologize and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

- When users put `y` or `Y` to column `K` at the sheet of `2018 2 Week Snapshot for Jim` on the active spreadsheet, you want to copy only the values of `B:K` to the last row at the sheet of "Test Sheet" on the spreadsheet of `1dSJOOw_oLVc6Nf-C0MY9715tZGuh69kR6-j_m8EJ-So`.

  - Spreadsheet of `15RWoaW8tRLVGOTDrZvBLJwx0beWEsV3x8pfwGe2zMfc` is the active spreadsheet.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification poonts:

- `set` of `setValues()` is lower case.
- `values` of `setValues(values)` is 2 dimentional array.

  - The range for `setValues(values)` is the range for putting the values.
- When you use `onEdit()`, you can use an event object.

The script which reflected above is as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var sourceSheetName = "2018 2 Week Snapshot for Jim";
  var destinationSpreadsheetId = "1dSJOOw_oLVc6Nf-C0MY9715tZGuh69kR6-j_m8EJ-So";
  var destinationSheetName = "Test Sheet";

  if (e.source.getSheetName() == sourceSheetName && e.range.getA1Notation()[0] == "K" && e.value.toUpperCase() == "Y") {
    var sourceValues = e.source.getRange("B:K").getValues().filter(function(e){return e.filter(String).length > 0});
    var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheetId);
    var ts = tss.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);
    ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow() + 1, 1, sourceValues.length, sourceValues[0].length).setValues(sourceValues);
  }
}
```

#### Note :

- Before you use this script, please install `myFunction()` as an installable trigger.

#### References:

- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

If I misunderstand your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: @tehhowch Thank you for your comment. I had forgotten about it. I updated it.