# Script for copying parts of a google spreadsheet row to another spreadsheet and adding a value all based on a cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am very new to coding and really struggling writing this code. I am hoping someone out there can help me. Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

When a "y" or "Y" is placed in column 19 ("S") on "Reviewed 2018 2 Week Snapshot for Jim" I want to copy columns B:G & J:R of that row.

Place that copied row on a different spreadsheet titled "Accounting" with a tab titled "Unprocessed Acct Data" on Columns C:Q.

I then need to write in column B of that pasted row "JT".

Finally, update the original "y" to Copied".

Here is a link to both test documents incase it helps.

[2 week Snapshot](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q8NDK3U2wIRxOdn_LK2WvGZbpttYD2A1f4eqYqgpoWw/edit?usp=sharing)

[Accounting](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l1f6SrN7d6hYDhfv8W_ne15vAd7xSJlC6138jpoXpC4/edit?usp=sharing)

```
function myFunction(e) {
  var sourceSheetName = "Reviewed 2018 2 Week Snapshot for Jim";
  var destinationSpreadsheetId = "1l1f6SrN7d6hYDhfv8W_ne15vAd7xSJlC6138jpoXpC4";
  var destinationSheetName = "Unprocessed Acct Data";

  if (e.source.getSheetName() == sourceSheetName && e.range.getcolumn() == 19 && e.value.toUpperCase() == "Y") {
    var sourceValues = e.source.getRange("B:G" && "J:R").getValues().filter(function(e){return e.filter(String).length > 0});
    var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheetId);
    var ts = tss.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);
    ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow() + 1, 1, sourceValues.length, sourceValues[0].length).setValues(sourceValues);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding for your question is correct, how about this modification? I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as one of them.

#### Modification points:

- Retrieve values of "B:R" as a source values from `Reviewed 2018 2 Week Snapshot for Jim`.

  - Values from column "B" to column "R" of a row that `Y` was put is retrieved.
- Retrieve values of "B:G" and "J:R" from the source values, and add "JT".
- Put the modified values to "B:Q" to `Unprocessed Acct Data` of Spreadsheet with the file ID of `1l1f6SrN7d6hYDhfv8W_ne15vAd7xSJlC6138jpoXpC4`.
- Modify `Y` to `Copied` on `Reviewed 2018 2 Week Snapshot for Jim`.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
if (e.source.getSheetName() == sourceSheetName && e.range.getcolumn() == 19 && e.value.toUpperCase() == "Y") {
  var sourceValues = e.source.getRange("B:G" && "J:R").getValues().filter(function(e){return e.filter(String).length > 0});
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheetId);
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);
  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow() + 1, 1, sourceValues.length, sourceValues[0].length).setValues(sourceValues);
}
```

To:

```
if (e.source.getSheetName() == sourceSheetName && e.range.getColumn() == 19 && e.value.toUpperCase() == "Y") {
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var sourceValues = e.source.getRange("B" + row + ":R" + row).getValues()[0];
  var values = [sourceValues.slice(0, 6).concat(sourceValues.slice(8, 17))];
  values[0].unshift("JT");
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationSpreadsheetId);
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName(destinationSheetName);
  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow() + 1, 2, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  e.range.setValue("Copied");
}
```

#### Note:

- In your shared Spreadsheet, there are several projects and functions. So when you use this modified script, please give a new function name (for example, it's `myFunction2(e)`) and please install the trigger to it. If the function name is duplicated, the script doesn't work correctly.

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: You answer works perfectly in test sheets. When I bring it over to the actual sheet and replace the Spreadsheet with the file ID it stops working. I have tried both triggers onEdit and on minute every minute. How do I test to see where it is failing?

Comment: @Leilani Thank you for replying. I'm relieved to know that my understanding for your question was correct and the script worked. For your new issue, unfortunately, I cannot understand about your situation. Those are about ``stops working``, the modified script and your Spreadsheet. Can you provide them? If you can do, please add it to your question. I would like to think of your new issue by knowing that how you modified the script and set it. I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Leilani As the important points, I think that if the format and sheet names of the Spreadsheet are the same between Spreadsheet of your question and your actual Spreadsheet and the function is installed as a trigger, the script works. So at first, please confirm them. And also can you confirm whether there are no the duplicate function names in the several projects of your Spreadsheet? Even if you confirmed them, when the issue was not resolved, can you provide the information I commented above?

Comment: I have confirmed the names of the sheets and that there is no duplicate functions titled "myFunction(e)". Unfortunately my companies google policy is very locked down so I am unable to share the actual sheets.

Can I add logs to this to see where it might be failing?

Comment: @Leilani I cannot directly resolve the issues without the detail information. I'm really sorry for my poor skill. But for example, how about copy the values of actual sheet to the worked sheet using the modified script? In that case, the environment is the same with the worked sheet. Even if you did it, if it didn't work, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet which replicates the same issue? And can I ask you about ``stops working``? I cannot understand about this meaning.